# Should I leave the parent pom in SNAPSHOT or pass it to RELEASE when releasing one of the parent's modules

Tags: maven

I would like to have more information about Maven best practices when releasing projects.

Say I have a parent pom with **N** modules. All are in **SNAPSHOT** versions including the parent. If I want to release one but not all of the modules, should I pass version for the parent pom project in RELEASE, or leave it in SNAPSHOT?

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more generally speaking, there are huge advantages in terms of simplicity, and very little disadvantages (a bit more hard drive consumption on the Nexus box), to keeping all version numbers uniform across a parent-child structure project, including keeping their RELEASE / SNAPSHOT status in sync. By always doing simultaneous releases of all modules, you do not have to keep in mind and manage the component inter-dependencies. You do not need to announce the releases to those clients, who only depend on a component that has not really changed.

That being said, if you do decide to "micro manage" a parent-child structure project, and every time to release only a certain subset of components, I would follow the following rules:

1.keep a component in its old RELEASE version until it needs to change. Promote it to the next SNAPSHOT only once it has been modified.

1a.That applies to parent poms too.

2.if a module depends on another module that has been modified, that counts as a modification of the former module as well

(if you want to modify a dependency, but to keep the item that depends on it in its old version, it helps a lot in terms of consistency and being able to reason about what is going on to simply branch out, and modify and release the dependency in a separate branch, in which the item that depends on it is also considered as being modified, but from where we do not release it. This helps you keep in mind that the dependency and the item that depends on it are being released from different branches, and are therefore deliberately inconsistent with each other at present.)

2a.this extends to cases where instead of "depends on a module that" we have "has a parent that". In a lot of ways, parents are like dependencies, in maven.

3.when you want to release (promote to the next RELEASE version) a module, you need to also release all modified modules it depends on (including its modified parents)

Respecting these will keep your project in a consistent state and make it easy to reason about its status, in my experience.

Since your parent is in SNAPSHOT, I assume it has been modified. Therefore you need to bump it to the next RELEASE when releasing the child you want to release.

If the parent has not changed since its last release, you could have kept it in its last RELEASE version, and this way you would not need to release it now together with the child that "depends on" (in terms of being its child) it.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing 'All are in SNAPSHOT versions including the parent' you should not set in your parent SNAPSHOT in this way you can't release all the project. 
If you want to release only a subpart of the project then make an other parent and include between your parent and all the projects or use as an other parent. In fact you have your reason to release only subset of your project and in this way you have a better documentation of your work.